# Expressing the Principal Value of 1/x

Tags: distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value

I'm a graduate student and taking a course in analysis and came upon this definition for the cauchy principal value for 1/x, can someone kindly explain how this equality comes about and perhaps provide a literature link to this equality? Thank You :)
$$
\lim_{a \to +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R} } \frac{(1-cos(ax))\varphi(x) }{x} dx = p.v.(\frac{1}{x}) 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sense of distributions, $\cos(ax) \to 0$ as $a \to \pm\infty$ because the close "peaks" and "valleys" will cancel. Therefore, $\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x} \to \frac{1-0}{x} = \frac{1}{x}$ at least away from $x=0.$

At $x=0$ the expression removes the infinities since 
$$
\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x} 
= \frac{1-(1-\frac12(ax)^2+O(x^4)}{x}
= \frac12 a^2 x + O(x^3).
$$

Probably the construction of the expression was based on the above facts.

Comment: could you explain how cos(ax) became 1-0.5(ax)^2+O(x^4)? and what is O(x) in this sense? also when u say cos(ax) tends to 0 as a goes to infinity, is this a consequence of the definition of a distribution in the integral form? (which is what u probably meant by close peaks and valleys i suppose?) thanks

Comment: It's the first terms of the [Maclaurin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions) of $\cos(ax)$. The $O(\ldots)$ part is [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for the tail.

Comment: I see thank you, could u elaborate more on what ''close peaks and valleys will cancel out''? thank you

Comment: Look at the graph of $\cos(ax)$ for some rather high value of $a$. The function oscillates quickly and has positive "peaks" and negative "valleys", even after multiplication with some smooth function (like $\varphi$). When you then integrate the "peaks" and "valleys" will cancel each other.